# Add multiple elements to JList

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jlist

I need to save on a `jList` multiple values coming from a specific source.

Inside the for cycle i generate both a `jComboBox` and bot a `Model` for a `Jlist` declared above in code (so not visible in this piece of code)
What i don't understand, maybe it's a simple problem, is why the jComboBox has all elements taken from the array `channelId` instead Jlist saves only the last element.

```
DefaultListModel jList1Model;
private void printChannelData(Channel channel, String nodeName) {   
    String[] channelId = { channel.getId()+" - "+nodeName/*+" - "+channel.getName()*/};
    jList1Model = new DefaultListModel();

    for (int i=0; i < channelId.length; i++) {
        //Adds element to the Single Channel Loading ComboBox
        channelIdComboBox.addItem(channelId[i]);
        //Adds elements to the Multiple Channel Loading ComboBox
        jList1Model.addElement(channelId[i]); 

    }
    jList1.setModel(jList1Model);   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You recreate the `ListModel` every time you call `printChannelData()` (probably in a loop somewhere). Create the `ListModel` outside, and inside the method just add to the model.

And `channelId` is a `String[]`, but only contains one item. I don't know what you were trying to do with it.

```
DefaultListModel<String> jList1Model = new DefaultListModel<>();

// probably a loop where you call printChannelData()
List<ChannelData> channels = ...;
for (ChannelData cd : channels) {
    printChannelData(cd, "whatever");
}


private void printChannelData(Channel channel, String nodeName) {   
    String channelId = channel.getId() + " - " + nodeName + " - " + channel.getName();
    for (int i=0; i < channelId.length; i++) {
        //Adds element to the Single Channel Loading ComboBox
        channelIdComboBox.addItem(channelId[i]);
        //Adds elements to the Multiple Channel Loading ComboBox
        jList1Model.addElement(channelId[i]); 
    }
    jList1.setModel(jList1Model);   
}
```

Comment: channelId it's an array of string and it's ok in this way, you have right for creating ListModel outside, what a stupid error, but thank you very much